# Iframes in Micros POS

Tags: point-of-sale

I am currently working for one proposal and looking feasibility of the solution.

The functionality we are trying to achieve is to display customer profile in the format of popup (or Iframe) when Hotel Personnel click a custom profile button on Hotel Booking screen.

I here consider Hotel Booking system using Micros 5 and Iframe/Popup will hit web service on runtime to load the customer profile.

Iframe can be open as a separate or on the same window, any things looks good in assumption.

I dont have any experience in Micros, neither didn't find of any documentation which can help me to understand the feasibility of the solution.

If any one has experience in customization of Micros, any inputs would be greatful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't strictly true that MICROS WS5 has no Internet access.

It is true that most MICROS workstations run Windows CE. Others run Microsoft's POSready OS which is based on Windows XP.

Older workstations run CE 4.2, newer workstations run CE 6.0. Both CE 4.2 & CE 6.0 ship with a very old version of IE. It is possible to write a CE executable which loads IE in a window and loads a web page. However, because the version of IE is so old it would be difficult if not impossible to load anything like a modern web app.

The ISL language, also referred to as SIM, is a specialized scripting language which is available on some, but not all, MICROS POS and PMS products. The availability of the SIM interface depends on the POS product, not the workstation.

Where it is supported, ISL scripts are directly called from the POS software, either by linking to a touchscreen button or by linking to events defined by the POS software. ISL gives you the the ability to do things like begin checks, add items, etc. It isn't pretty but fairly complex POS add-ons have been written using ISL.

It is true that from ISL it is possible to call out to Windows DLL's. In most cases it would be necessary to have both a Win32 and CE (>=4.2) version of the DLL unless you are certain that only CE workstations are being used. It is also possible to directly launch a Windows executable (again, either Win32 or CE) from ISL rather than using a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Hi got answer for this question by Robert Johnson. Thanks.

Micros WS 5 terminals typically run windows CE 6.0 and have no internet access.
Custom applications have to be developed using a special micros keystroke language called ISL to make SIMs which may call out to DLLs (which have to be CE 6.0) compatible.

The apps then need to route their request via the Micros server to the internet.